# CoreData ContextObjectsDidChangeNotification called from another thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, uimanageddocument

Recently while investigating some weird UI behavior of UIPickerView, I reached the conclusion that is was because I was reloading its components in a selector that was called observing the **NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification**. The thing is, At least I was pretty sure this will be always be called from the main thread. But I was wrong. I'm using UIManagedDocument, and sometimes I get the following notification from another thread:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x14a2664b0 {name = NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification; object = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x14a3e1be0>; userInfo = {
invalidatedAll =     (
    "0xd00000000d5c000e <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/AdditionalAssetAttributes/p855>",
    "0xd00000000d58000e <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/AdditionalAssetAttributes/p854>",
    "0xd00000000d5c000c <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/Asset/p855>",
    "0xd00000000d58000c <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/Asset/p854>",
    "0xd000000001d40018 <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/SidecarFile/p117>",
    "0xd000000001d00018 <x-coredata://B12EF0BD-E372-44D2-AF2F-8E28C5EF3E00/SidecarFile/p116>"
);
managedObjectContext = "<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x14a3e1be0>";
```

My question is: Does anyone knows why this notification is being called? What is the purpose of the **invalidateAll** elements. Also I have no Idea what **AdditionalAssetAttributes** or **SidecarFile** are.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you observing `NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification` or `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`? Your question says one but your output shows the other.

Comment: I think the `NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification` is the value of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: Just tried here: `NSLog(@"%@", NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification);` prints: `NSObjectsChangedInManagingContextNotification`

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this notification as well regularly as of iOS 11. There's not much documentation, but it seems if the notification's `userInfo` contains the key `NSInvalidatedAllObjectsKey` (**invalidatedAll**), then you must refetch all NSManagedObject's from the document that your application has references too. Failure to do see leaves them all no longer usable. The contents of the array can be ignored (e.g. I often find it is empty)